# What does an increased time constant of a capacitor do?

Tags: electricity, capacitance

If a capacitor is being charged to any voltage, what effect would increasing the time constant have on it and if a graph of Charge Q/Time T was plotted to give a positive decreasing gradient, how would an increased time constant affect the graph?

Comment: This looks like a homeowork question. Also, did you read the Wikipedia article about [time constants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_constant)?

Comment: It's not from a homework question however my questioning stems from reading a textbook, but that failed to answer my query.

Comment: Hi Ed Spencer. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: By "gradient" do you mean the slope, $\frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{\mathrm{d}t}$?

Comment: A capacitor does not have any time constant.

Answer (score 1):

The time constant is the time an exponential takes to reach about a third of its original value. Increasing the time constant in this case would have the effect of "pulling" the graph of the function to the right. In this case, we're dealing with an equation of the form $Q(t)=1-e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}$, with $\tau$ the time constant. In this case, the time constant is the time it takes for the charge to *increase* to about two thirds its *asymptotic* value of 1 (or $CV_{battery}$ to be precise).

Comment: Could you say the gradient is less?

Comment: If you look at the derivatives of Q(t) and compare them for different time-constants, this should tell you. One way of doing this is to take the ratio of the derivatives for two different time constants. In general, the gradient may be less or greater depending on what time you evaluate the gradient at, even though the graph may appear to flatten out as the time constant increases.