# How can I rearrange an equation to find a gradient for a capacitor?

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance

If I plot R on the x axis and T on the y axis to give a straight line graph, and I am given that $V$ = $V_0$ * e^(-t/RC) then how can I prove that the gradient of the graph is equivalent to $C$ * ln3, if $C$ is capacitance?

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/177397/2451

Comment: As written I don't think what you state _can_ be proven unless certain other assumptions are made. What is this $T$ you are plotting? Time until what?

Comment: Time taken for the capacitor to discharge 2/3 of its initial voltage.

Comment: Hi Ed Spencer. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the time you plot is the time to discharge 2/3 of the initial voltage, then from your equation (where I put $RC=\tau$)

$$V(t) = v_0 e^{-t/\tau}$$

you can see that

$$e^{-t/\tau}=\frac13$$

Taking the natural log on both sides:

$$-\frac{t}{\tau} = -\log(3)$$

Substituting $\tau=RC$ and rearranging, we get

$$T = RC\log(3)$$

So the slope of the plot of $T$ as a function of R has a slope equal to $C\log(3)$.